# How to check if model has existing model associations in Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two ActiveRecord models (Book, Ad) which are associated. In my query I want to fetch books which has got 1 or more ads. What would be the best way to do this?

```
# in controller:
@books = Book.where(book has got 1 or more ads).last(20)

# Book model:
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :ads, :dependent => :destroy
   ...
end

# Ad model:
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :book
   ...
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use `joins`:

`Book.joins(:ads)`

`joins` allows you to do all of this in one query, and this would give you all `Books` that have a `book_id` on `Ad` set.

So for your controller, you'd have:

`@books = Book.joins(:ads).last(20)`

Comment: No problem.  If this helped, please click the green checkmark next to the answer to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

in your controller

```
subquery = Ad.select("book_id").group(:book_id).having("COUNT(*) >= 1").to_sql
@books =   Book.where("id IN (#{subquery})").last(20)
```

Comment: Just a quick side note, you don't need to separate the subsquery like that. You can simply do `Book.where(id=>Ad.select("book_id").group(:book_id).having("COUNT(*) >= 1"))`, and the subquery will be performed in the `where` clause in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution would be

```
Ad.all.map{|ad| ad.book}.uniq.last(20)
```

This will return the last 20 unique books in an `Array` because if a `Ad` exists then it has a `Book` thus the Book has 1 or more `Ads`